# ADB driver for Sony Xperia Z2a (D6563)

Tags: adb, sony, sony-xperia

So I wanted to start learning Android Programming, but I cannot find ADB driver for my phone for USB debugging. I tried looking at the http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/ but the Xperia Z2a D6563 does not exist there.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is off-topic here, as your are asking for tools.

Comment: There is a Xperia Z2 driver there, did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this exe.
Here's the installer file:
http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi